# Blurred borders in Cairo

Tags: cairo, vala

What is proper way to draw a blurred rectangular border using the [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) API? I am writing a patch for [Shotwell](http://yorba.org/shotwell/) to add a blurred shadow to the thumbnails in the thumbnail view.

For now I am experimenting with manual blurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up drawing the border with linear and radial gradients.

Here is a small visualization. The lines symbolize the linear grandients and the 0 the radial gradients.

```
        0
        |
        |
 0------0
```